# Is there such a thing as complex conjugate of the first order correction of a wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory

If I am given the first-order correction to a wave function as

$$\left|\psi_n^{(1)}\right\rangle = \sum_{m \neq n} \frac{ \left\langle\psi_m^0\right|H'\left|\psi_n^0\right\rangle }{E_n^0 - E_m^0}\left|\psi_m^0\right\rangle,$$

then does that mean the following,

$$\left\langle\psi_n^{(1)}\right| = \sum_{m \neq n} \frac{ \left\langle\psi_n^0\right|H'\left|\psi_m^0\right\rangle }{E_n^0 - E_m^0}\left\langle\psi_m^0\right|,$$

is true?

Note that $H'$ is the perturbation Hamiltonian.

The goal of this question is to allow me to calculate the first order correction of the momentum operator, which I am assuming can be calculated as

$$\left\langle\hat p^{(1)}\right\rangle = \left\langle\psi_n^{(1)}\right|\hat p\left|\psi_n^{(1)}\right\rangle.$$

Comment: You did this correctly.

Comment: "first order correction"  according to which parameter? You may check that your expression for $<\hat p^{(1)}>$ is actualy second order in the perturbation hamiltonian.

Comment: @GiorgioP So I want to find the change of the expectation value of $\hat p$ to first order of H'. How can you tell that what I have is second order in the H'. I am having trouble expanding that expression.

Comment: It is second order because within the integral you have to multiply two first order corrections to wavefunction, each of them containing matrix elements of the perturbing Hamiltonian.

Comment: Ah I see. Then the expression that I actually need to use instead of what I have in the question is $<\psi_n^0|\hat p|\psi_n^1> + <\psi_n^1|\hat p|\psi_n^0>$, right?

Comment: Right.    Each order in perturbation thepry requires that you collect all the terms with the same power of perturbation.

Comment: I see. Thank you.